# Как получить список всех констант класса

Tags: php, laravel

Нужно получить список констант из модели, причём важно и имя и значение, чтоб можно было сохранить их в масив
пример класса:

```
class Log extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'log';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = ['model', 'action', 'value', 'old', 'new', 'time', 'user_id'];

    const MODEL_USER = 1;
    const MODEL_TEAM = 2;
    const MODEL_PLAYER = 3;
    const MODEL_TEAM_PLAYER = 4;

    const ACTION_CREATE = 1;
    const ACTION_UPDATE = 2;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

С помощью [ReflectionClass::getConstants](http://php.net/manual/ru/reflectionclass.getconstants.php):

```
class A {
  const STATUS_ACTIVE = 1;
  public static function getConstants() {
    return (new \ReflectionClass(static::class))->getConstants();
  }
}
var_dump(A::getConstants()); // ['STATUS_ACTIVE' => 1]
```

Вы получите список **всех** констант класса. Обычно необходимости в этом нет, лучше сгруппировать константы по интерфейсам:

```
interface IStatus {
  const STATUS_ACTIVE = 1;
  const STATUS_PENDING = 2;
  const STATUS_REMOVED = 4;

}
interface IAction {
  const ACTION_CREATE = 1;
  const ACTION_UPDATE = 2;
}
class A implements IStatus {
  public static function getStatusConstants() {
      return (new \ReflectionClass(IStatus::class))->getConstants();
  }
  public static function getActionConstants() {
      return (new \ReflectionClass(IAction::class))->getConstants();
  }
}
var_dump(A::getStatusConstants());
```

[Демонстрация](https://3v4l.org/K3jpH)

---

Также можно избавиться от рефлексии, просто добавив в интерфейс ещё одну константу со списком:

```
interface IStatus {
  const STATUS_ACTIVE = 1;
  const STATUS_PENDING = 2;
  const STATUS_REMOVED = 4;
  const LIST = [
      'STATUS_ACTIVE' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE, 
      'STATUS_PENDING' => self::STATUS_PENDING, 
      'STATUS_REMOVED' => self::STATUS_REMOVED
  ];
}

class A implements IStatus {
  public static function getStatusConstants() {
      return IStatus::LIST;
  }
}
var_dump(A::getStatusConstants());
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот тут вот есть ответ на Ваш вопрос: http://php.net/manual/ru/reflectionclass.getconstants.php

Comment: Единственное, что  - Reflection - это очень медленно и "не продакшин"

Comment: у меня не находит этот класс

Comment: Скорее всего дело в неймспейсе